# I am looking for a TYPO3 gallery extension where i can link images to pages?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am searching for an extension for TYPO3 ver.: `9.5.x` which shows a basic image gallery. Each image should contain a link to a different page of my homepage. Does anyone know such an extension or is there another way to get this functionality?

Comment: Please improve your question, add more details, and fix spelling, for an instance TYPO3 as a name is written always with uppercase. For your problem install and configure `mask` extension, so you will be able to create such a solution without big programming skills.

Comment: @biesior I have edited the question. I hope it's no easier to understand what i need? The mask extension might work but it seems to consume alot of time - i think there must be a finished extension already?

Comment: It doesn't, when you'll install it you need just several tweaks in the generated template. On the other hand - true - it's not _out-of-the-box solution_ and requires some work. Sorry I don't use any ready to use extensions, as such things always do myself, so can;t help you better.

Comment: You need to search the extension repository and choose solution which best fits your requirements.

Comment: @biesior Thank you for your hel,  i have now found the perfect extension (basically the most basic extension) - its the bootstrap package extension. It comes with cards of pages / gallerys aso.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the perfect solution: the extension `bootstrap package`.
For example there is a new content element called "cards of subpages" - its the perfect solution. You just need to make some basic changes in the extension to remove the text which is created.

Comment: You've to document the changes for yourself because when the extension is updated any "hacks" directly in the extension are lost. Therefore changes like that are usually avoided.

Comment: @David Can i not just block any updates for the extension by editing something? And if yes how to do that.

Comment: It's possible but also not advisable, I did it with one extension for a customer and it can get a big burden to come after some time on the track again because at some time you've to update it for compatibility reasons. Nevertheless, here the description: in `state` of the array in ext_emconf,php you can enter the value `excludeFromUpdates`, it's described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/DeclarationFile/Index.html#declaration-file-ext-emconf-php

Comment: `bootstrap_package` is Extbase extension with Fluid templates which can be extended via copying files into custom location and with some TypoScript modifications, so you don't have to modify original extension's code to get changes. On the other hand, it's quite huge and definitely it's overload to use it just for some clickable gallery.